# Emit links between 2 doc's geopositions with CouchDB+GeoCouch

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, geocoding, geojson

I have a CouchDB where each document represents a point on a map. Furthermore, each doc has a list of ids and each of those ids represents a target for a link on the map. I wonder if it's possible to create a GeoCouch spatial index where the keys are GeoJSON representations of the links (e.g. LineStrings). I give an example below.

Let's assume I have these 2 documents:

```
{
  _id: "doc1",
  latlng: [52.52, 13.13],     // geoposition of doc1
  links: ["doc2", "doc3"]     // links to doc2 and doc3
}
```

and

```
{
  _id: "doc2",
  latlng: [53.53, 14.14],     // geoposition of doc2
  links: ["doc1"]             // link to doc1
}
```

What I would like to have is a spatial index where I can query all links in a given bounding box. However, in the CouchDB/GeoCouch map function which es run for doc1 I don't have access to the geoposition of doc2.

Does anybody see another way to achieve a spatial index for the links in the above situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache CouchDB you could emit the links [as `_id`](http://web.archive.org/web/20100323024421/http://blog.couch.io/post/446015664/whats-new-in-apache-couchdb-0-11-part-two-views), query it with `include_docs=true` and use a _list function to transform it to whatever you want.

Sadly GeoCouch doesn't support the `include_docs` parameter, so it won't work there. For GeoCouch you would need to make two requests. First get the links and then get all that documents with `keys=[the-ids]`. You can optionally do the second request on a View and use a _list function to get GeoJSON out of it.

Comment: Thx @vmx, at the moment I do it in [couchmap](https://github.com/andrenarchy/couchmap) exactly as you proposed. I submit two requests: one via a GeoCouch index to obtain all nodes in a bounding box with the corresponding link ids. The second request is a plain multi-fetch request with all ids from the link arrays. So if this solution is the best I can implement with GeoCouch, I'm satisfied. :)